# Widget based on available inventory (Magento)

Tags: magento

I am using **Magento 1.6** to build an e-commerce store. I want to show a widget "Going Fast" which will list the products having less than 10 items in stock/inventory.

I found an extension "Flexible Product" using which you can create a widget based on attribute filtering however I doubt inventory is an attribute so it won't work to best of my understanding.

Can someone share some insights on how/where to hack the code to show such products which are about to end. If it can be done by adding a CMS page with code then it would be great.

Comment: And your question is? Questions on Stack Overflow are expected to generally relate to programming or software development in some way, within the scope defined in the [faq](http://stackoverflow.com/faq).

Comment: It's indeed related to programming. What made you think it's not?

Comment: If it is then stackowerflow expects that you express it in a way so others also would understand that it is related to programming :)

Comment: Well, if you didn't understand that doesn't mean others too won't.

Comment: Added some more details. I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get a collection of low inventory products you would do something like this.

```
$productsCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('reports/product_lowstock_collection');
$productsCollection->filterByIsQtyProductTypes()
    ->useNotifyStockQtyFilter();

//Then do something with them.
echo $productsCollection->getFirstItem()->getName();
```